# loaded SWF (using Loader) event listeners sometimes fails

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i made a SWF which contains a loader which loads any SWF file passed to it... the problem I'm encountering is that for some SWFs, some event listeners doesn't fire anymore... my own SWF file (which contains the loader) doesn't really have any other element except for the Loader object and so I cannot understand what seems to be preventing the loaded SWF (loaded by my Loader) from receiving some mouse events

Got some more details about my problem... it seems that the for the SWF where I'm having this problem, the listener seems to be tied up to a location in the stage or somewhere else, and so whenever I resize, the listeners is not responding on the right place, for example, the button appears on a certain position but the listener's hit test or whatever the SWF is using to detect the mouse click is positioned somewhere else

Comment: where do you put the loader event listener?

here: `loader.loaderInfo.addEventListener();` or here : `loader.addEventListener();`?

Comment: its not the loader which is having the problem, but the loaded SWF (the SWF being loaded by the loader)... it could probably be because the SWF has set up its own listener in the wrong way because i'm getting mouse clicks events but on a different location...

All i can think of is why is it that if the SWF is not loaded inside a loader, it resizes and repositions its listeners correctly, but if SWF is loaded inside a loader, it cannot seem to reposition its listener's location... because the mouse click listeners seems to be dependent on a coordinate and not an object

Comment: are you using inside your loaded swf, `stage` or `root` parameters to get childredn or to add events?

Answer (score 0):

I've encounter such problem as well. It's not the listeners that changed their location, it's the Mouse orientation that changed.

Did you made any scale modifications? This what caused the problem for me.

You can try and fix it by changing the `stage.scaleMode` to:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
```

Solved that problem for me.

Note you can also set the `stage.align`.

Comment: i already have stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; and stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; on my code, I guess this is also the problem because I'm using the same SWF for loading AS2 and AS3 coded SWFs